# chown: cannot access '/var/lib/odoo': No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, dpkg, odoo

I want to install odoo 14 on ubuntu 20.04.2, everytime I want to install odoo's dependencies this error comes up:

```
chown: cannot access '/var/lib/odoo': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package odoo (--configure): installed odoo
package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing: odoo 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was following the installation instruction on https://www.candidroot.com/blog/our-candidroot-blog-1/post/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-67 and the error comes up when I run step5.

I tried other solutions but the error is still there.

Comment: Run `sudo mkdir /var/lib/odoo` and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative solution as well - manually install [deb-package from Ubuntu 21.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/odoo-14):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/odoo/odoo-14_14.0.0+dfsg.2-5build1_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./odoo-14_14.0.0+dfsg.2-5build1_all.deb
```